# Rename batch file Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a 123-5678.tiff file I would like to copy and rename as 20 different names like

```
4542345.tiff
4542346.tiff
4542347.tiff
4542349.tiff
4542350.tiff
4542351.tiff
4542353.tiff
4542354.tiff
4542355.tiff
4542357.tiff
4542358.tiff
4542359.tiff
4542360.tiff
```

This 20 or 50 names are given in the form of text file or Excel file.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f %%f in (filelist.txt) do copy "123-5678.tiff" "%%f"
```

For each line in filelist.txt (containing a file name) do copy the source file to target

It can work as is or fail for a bunch or reasons. There is too little information.